# how to skip the first 2 rows on my Csv file

Tags: php, csv

Here is my Csv Upload Script how will i make it ignore the first 2 rows of my Csv File.
Can't find a proper way to skip/ignore it.
A little help pls?

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    if ( isset( $_FILES['userfile'] ) )
    {
      $csv_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

      if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )
        exit('File not found.');



      if (($handle = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
      {
          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
          {  
            {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `prelims` (`name`,`grade`) VALUES('$data[0]','$data[2]')";  
            $exec = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());    

            echo ("The following data has been added to the database");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can't you just start iterating on the third line of the csv?

Comment: A little elaboration on previous attempts pls? Like have you tried a counter and `continue`, or prefacing two empty fgets/fgetcsv calls?

Comment: This script is working but i just need to skip the first 2 rows to finish it..

Answer (score 2):

```
fgetcsv($handle); // get line 0 and move pointer to line 1
fgetcsv($handle); // get line 1 and move pointer to line 2
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
...
```

you may also want to do some error checking on top of that to make sure your CSV has at least 2 lines in it.

Comment: fseek works in bytes from the beginning of the file. It does not jump through rows

Comment: @magalter, thanks for pointing it out. I did not realize that until now. I had removed the invalid piece of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that part of the above answer is incorrect. The line
    `fseek($handle, 2);`
does *not* seek forward two lines; it seeks forward two bytes. To skip an arbitrary number of lines, you could do this:

```
$skipLines = 5000; // or however many lines you want to skip
$lineNum = 1;
if ($skipLines > 0) {
    while (fgetcsv($handle)) {
        if ($lineNum==$skipLines) { break; }
        $lineNum++;
    }
}
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    // starts getting data from 5001st row
}
```